# Office 2013 gets custom installer removed after update to Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-7, microsoft-office

My pc was win 7 pro - I upgraded to Windows 10 pro. I had Office 2013 installed and all works well in Windows 10. However, if I want to add or remove Office features I cannot. The add/remove programs have a  modify option, but it simply askes you to do a repair.
Previously in Win 7 you got this option to modify your current Office installation.
EG: I had not installed powerpoint previously, I cannot install it now.

Should I run the original office setup cdrom to get the options, but this could mess up my installation.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The folder containing the Office installation files is still there somewhere in the C:\Windows.old folder. (This contains the original Windows 7 installation.)
You will have to do some digging there to find that folder (its actually a foilder tree) and then move it to the same location under c:\Windows.

If the C:\Windows.old folder is already removed you need the original installation media and run the Office setup from there.
Just remember to use WindowsUpdate to update Office to the latest release any time you add/remove components via the original installation media. If you don't do that some Office components may not run or be very unstable because you have a mix of older and newer versions.
(It is probably even easier to just remove Office completely and do a full re-install, simply installing ALL of it.)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Office 2013 are you using now?

For volume lincensed versions of Office, such as Professional Plus, Standard, we could run  **Setup.exe** (The executable program is included in installation file.) in maintenance mode and make changes to an existing Office installation.

I would take Office Professional Plus 2013 and a separate PowerPoint installation as an example.

- Copy the installation file to your computer first.
- Then write a config file named "PPT.xml" and saved it into **proplus.ww** folder.

`<Configuration Product="ProPlus">`
`<OptionState Id="PPTFiles" State="Local" Children="Force" />`
`<Display Level="None" CompletionNotice="No" SuppressModal="Yes" AcceptEula="Yes" />`
`</Configuration>`

[image]

- Generally, if you want to make changes to an existing Office
  installation, you could use the "/modify" option to add or remove
  features.

  Run the following commands, and please wait for a moment, then you could have a check.

`cd <the path of source files>`

`setup.exe /modify ProPlus /config proplus.ww\PPT.xml`

[image]

For other Office products, to get the Product ID, you may find them in the **setup.xml** which is in the **proplus.ww** folder.

More detailed information, please refer to "[/modify [ProductID]](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc178956(v=office.15)#modify-productid)" and "[OptionState element](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179195%28v%3Doffice.15%29#optionstate-element)".